# Is it possible to download a div content from HTML as a text file while you can also rename the file name?

Tags: javascript

I am able to make a copy of my `div` content and save it as a plain text file into my computer, but I am wondering if it is possible to rename the file while downloading it?

I have written something which will save the content directly and name it `myFile.txt`

Here is my function:

```
function downloadFile(){
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("output").innerText;
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

and `<button type="button" id="download" onclick="downloadFile()">Download Text File</button>`

So when I click on the button, it will start download automatically but I hope it will pop up some download window just like we normally download an application online, so I can rename the file and also change the directory where the file will be saved.

Comment: Just remove the `download` property?

Comment: Doesn’t it depend on browser? Chrome downloads automatically and Firefox asks. That is by default. But I think from `hiddenElement.click()` it’s passed to browser and out of control.

Comment: @Seb That's why I added a button to kind like let me decide when to download, otherwise Chrome will start downloading when the page is loaded

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I tried, no luck...

Comment: For renaiming you could create a function that asks the user for input and then sets that to `hiddenElement.download`. For changing download directory, it pretty much depends on browser.

Comment: I found out it is a browser issue. Should not set default folder for downloads. Solved, thank y'all!